# Need help for Jquery click on profile and show Bio content

Tags: jquery, image, toggle, jquery-hover

Can anyone help me? i have a trouble figuring out how to implement a script that when you click on any of the profile pictures it will show up a bios, kinda like this: https://vestar.com/company/leadership/  I only need at least one example script in jquery and from there i will handle the rest. Currently this is what i came up using a different script from from google search: http://derek.phgserver1.com/leadership/  I also need the feature that when you hover over the image and click that it will toggle just like what https://vestar.com/company/leadership/  did to their website. I hope someone here who can help me. Thanks

Comment: answered check it on click

Comment: done your another demand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FadeToggle` can do your work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){     
      var id = this.id;
      $(".bio").not("#"+id+"div").hide();
      $("#"+id+"div").fadeToggle(); 
   });
  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("button")) {
         $(".bio").fadeOut();
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
button{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
div{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:lightgrey;
 display:none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="first">First</button>
  <button id="second">Second</button>
  <br><br><br>
  <div id="firstdiv" class="bio">Hello First World Bio</div>
  <div id="seconddiv" class="bio">Hello Second World Bio</div>
</body>
```

The other problem of grayscale to colored will be done by simple css property `filter`.
**EDIT 2:** Added new functionality image will convert to rgb until users click anywhere in document.

```js
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
 if (!$(e.target).is("img")) {
   $("img").css("filter","grayscale(100%)");
 } 
});
$("img").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("filter","grayscale(0%)");
});
```

```css
img {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  transition-duration:0.2s;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="yourpiclink.png" />
```

Just add image link in img tag

Comment: Thank you Arhmed, I already got that covered though, the only thing i need was the image to change from gray to colored. If you can do a script that will look like the site i posted, should be great.

Comment: @ArchieValderrosa if consider green tick on this answer it will pleasure to me. By the way I am editing my own answer to change image from gray to color

Comment: Thanks, But i need the script to be somewhat similar to this site: https://vestar.com/company/leadership/  if you click on the bios image it will change to color and show the bios info, then after that if you click away or somewhere within that page it will go back to normal or its original state?

Comment: okay..let me edit question once more

Comment: Ok i need your help, the hover and click was fine for the image to change from gray scale to color, but that's not what i really wanted it to happen, it would be great if the image stays in color after clicking and then goes back to gray if you toggle it like click again and goes back to gray and also if i click anywhere the images should go back to its original gray color. i would prefer it to be jquery rather than css. because css only does the hover and the image won't stay just like the site i mentioned see example: https://vestar.com/company/leadership/

Comment: @ArchieValderrosa Done it take a look

Comment: No problem .God Blessed

Answer (score -1):

I think that you implement the first one.

For second you can use

> ```
> $("your picture selector").hover(function(){   $("your picture selector").animate({
> filter: grayscale(100%); }); });
> ```

or vise versa

> ```
> $("your picture selector").hover(function(){   $("your picture selector").animate({
> filter : grayscale(0%) }); });
> ```

you can use this tutorials:

[jQuery Effects - Animation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp)
 or 
[CSS filter Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll test the script you posted, appreciated much.

Comment: I'm sorry i have to open this issue again because none of the above help was able to accomplish what i need. Thanks Btw. for the people who helped me. I would like for someone to help me do exactly the same as this website has: https://vestar.com/company/leadership/, i'm talking about the "SENIOR MANAGEMENT TEAM" section where we click the photo of the member, click and un-click or click anywhere, hover etc. profile..., basically exactly what it does, if anyone please do take a time to check on how that site's "Senior Management" section functions. Thank you very much..